# Загрузка несколько фотографии VK (php)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Подскажите что не так пытаюсь сделать что бы грузились 1-5 фоток но одна грузится а все остальные нет

```
function load($src){
    $photo = (array)$this->getPhoto($src);
    $photo[$this->owner['type']] = $this->owner['value'];
    $data = $this->vk->get('photos.saveWallPhoto', $photo);
    return $data;
}

private function getPhoto($src){

    file_put_contents($name, file_get_contents($src));
    $ch = curl_init($this->getServer());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'file1' => '@/путь/vkAPI/tests/1.png','file2' => '@/путь/vkAPI/tests/5.png'
    ));
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    return json_decode($response);
}

private function getServer(){

    $data = $this->vk->get('photos.getWallUploadServer', array(
        $this->owner['type'] => $this->owner['value'],
    ));
    return $data->response->upload_url;
}
```